# Cannot find the right logic to translate the NSDate to string

Tags: swift, xcode

I am very new to swift and found this one difficult, so its saying that it cannot be parsed to a variable because its not a string.

I searched and found something but it was not related near to my type of code so I am kindly asking for it :)

```
    let dateFormatterGet = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterGet.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

    let dateFormatterPrint = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatterPrint.dateFormat = "MMM dd,yyyy"

    let date: NSDate? = dateFormatterGet.date(from: currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate!) as NSDate?
    print(dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date! as Date))



    cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = date    // Error: Cannot assign value of type 'NSDate?' to type 'String?'
```

Comment: Not related to the question but all occurrences of `(NS)Date` are pointless in particular both bridge casts to and from `NSDate`. Delete the type annotation `: NSDate?` and both `as...` expressions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the correct `String` value, but assigning the variable `date` which typed as `NSDate?` to the `text` property, which should be a `String`.

Try doing this:

```
let dateString = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date! as Date)
cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = dateString
```

One piece of advice: don't force unwrap here (`date! as Date`). Instead, include a way to handle `nil` values for your "optional" `NSDate?` variable. One way to do this would look like this:

```
if let date = dateFormatterGet.date(from: currentVechicle.LastCommunicationDate!) as NSDate? {
  cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = dateFormatterPrint.string(from: date as Date)
} else {
  cell.perditsuarOutlet.text = "Empty or invalid date"
}
```

I know this looks like a lot of overhead, but it is worth it to avoid crashes down the line...

Answer (score 0):

- your **date** constant is an NSDate.
- and the cells **text** property is a String.

You can't pair the two together since they aren't the same type.

Since you can't change the cells **text** type, that only leaves you with 1 option. You'll have to turn the NSDate into a String.

I recommend taking a look at [Paul Hudsons 100 Days of Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/1/2/strings-and-integers). It was a fantastic resource when I first started. The link I've provided points to his lessons from Day 1 about Strings

Keep up the good work. I promise it gets better :)

Comment: Thanks a lott dear J, really appriciate it and will defo check it